# VLOOKUP to compare two columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use the result of vlookup and then evaluate the result of another column.
I have the following two tables:

Roster:

```
   ID  Current Employee
   12  Yes
   13  No
```

TableB:

```
   ID  In Roster & Current Employee
   12  ?
   13  ?
```

To make the check for if the employee is in Roster, I can do a simple Vlookup: 
`=IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Roster!A:A,2,FALSE))),"Yes","No")`
How do I check the two columns simultaneously to get the result of "In Roster & Current Employee"?

Comment: You could use COUNTIFS.

Comment: can you give me an example how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find COUNTIFS easier here:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Roster!A:A,A2,Roster!B:B,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```